# Unable to copy folder from application bundle to document directory

Tags: ios, iphone, nsfilemanager

I am trying to copy a folder from the application bundle to iphone document directory but it isnt happening.

I have used this codes

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"];


    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];

    NSError *error1;
    NSArray *resContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error: &error1];
    if (error1) {
        NSLog(@"error1 : %@",error1);
    }
    [resContents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         NSError* error;
         if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]
               copyItemAtPath:[sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:obj]
               toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:obj]
               error:&error])
             NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }];
}
```

And also tried this approach

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
     [self copyFolder];
    }

- (void) copyFolder {
    BOOL success1;
    NSFileManager *fileManager1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    fileManager1.delegate = self;
    NSError *error1;
    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath1 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Photos"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath1])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:writableDBPath1 withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error1];

    NSString *defaultDBPath1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"];
    NSLog(@"default path %@",defaultDBPath1);
    success1 = [fileManager1 copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath1 toPath:writableDBPath1 error:&error1];
    if (!success1 )
    {
        NSLog(@"error1 : %@",error1);
    } else {
    }
}

- (BOOL)fileManager:(NSFileManager *)fileManager shouldProceedAfterError:(NSError *)error copyingItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath{
    if ([error code] == 516) //error code for: The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Its display this error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x8a39800 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8a385b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/FC7F93EE-CFB7-41CF-975B-2E3B18760202/app.app/Photos, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Folder
>   )}

But Here is the folder

[image]

Comment: The yellow color Photos represents a group name.  A physical folder has a blue color.

Comment: Attention the "Photos" in your project not a real folder but the group (Images.xcassets for example is real folder)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119564/copy-images-from-an-app-to-documents-directory-and-rewrite-them-after-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Photos** seems like a group and not a folder reference. Hence all the images `photo1.jpg`.. etc are stored directly under your resource bundle.

The path `<resource_bundle>/Photos` does not exists. To verify this go to the application `.app`

```
.app->Right-click->Show Package Contents
```

Instead of adding Photos as a group, add it as Folder reference and under your target **Copy Bundle Resources** make sure the entire folder is added.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanx for reply. I have learned new thing today. Thanx to user523234 proff also.

Answer (score 1):

Your photos is not in the Photos directory. They just exist in `/Users/devubhamanek/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/FC7F93EE-CFB7-41CF-975B-2E3B18760202/MTPhotoViewer.app/` like `/Users/devubhamanek/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/FC7F93EE-CFB7-41CF-975B-2E3B18760202/MTPhotoViewer.app/photo1.jpg`

If you want to create an directory in bundle, you should add the files in Photos directory like this:
[image].

The folder in your project navigator should be:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you folder exists. 
You can easily assign your group in `XCode` to physical folder

Click on `group` and you'll find location setting on right pane.

Press on `folder` sign to choose physical folder `location`.

Actually this is really helpful to keep your project structure clean (not only in `XCode` project) but physically on disk.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Complete Solution Code**
Note: After creating folder with reference use following method.

```
func copyFolderFromThisAppMainToUserDocument(folderName: String) -> Bool {

    let fileMgr = FileManager.default
    let userDocumentURL = fileMgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let urlForCopy = userDocumentURL.appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)
    if let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: folderName, withExtension: "") {
        // if exist we will copy it
        do {
            try fileMgr.copyItem(at: bundleURL, to: urlForCopy)
            return true
        } catch let error as NSError { // Handle the error
            print("\(folderName) copy failed! Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            return false
        }
    } else {
        print("\(folderName) not exist in bundle folder")
        return false
    }
}
```